# How to setup OpenVPN on my Netgear Orbi Mesh router to be able to mask and change my location when using Kodi to watch sports

Tags: wireless-networking, router, openvpn, kodi

I use Kodi on an Nvidia Shield. I would like to to configure my Orbi Mesh router to run OpenVPN. Other VPN's will not run on the Orbi. I have multiple TV's with connected Shields, each will need to be able to switch locations on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CRKV2DfugI) might be just what you need. Also, do you mean changing locations like picking a specific country to watch the sports from for locality reasons? Or just like hiding your true location? The server you connect to should all be based on the OpenVPN config files you choose. Like for example, I use NordVPN, so I had to download their OpenVPN config profile so I could use Nord through OpenVPN, and when I went to download the .OVPN (config) file, there were like thousands of them, each corresponding with a specific server, in a specific location with specific uses. So check with your VPN provider.